# Android GCM Missing Registration

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i am using GCM n my project. 
i am trying to implement gcm but every time i am getting the error MissingRegistration.

below is the code

```
string regId =  "APA91bGdOrgXqDZkXQ75D_5voAjjr4S288L3JPtndSeuZndhCLieokzoZw4aKlzBKlsubdlRnRibNRAvJXWoBj6-Fi5cW2wpGOtqUPyeA13qvPMy766447ZbE-zP2L8kpHuYA20dD3LX2PKSuEn8AsL90v1QfLH9rw";
        var applicationID = "AIzaSyCGD36ySTZTEJ8vh6qcgMWVolKmqZjSUV0";



        var SENDER_ID = "MyProjectID";
        var value = "test message";
        System.Net.WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
            + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_ids=" + regId + "";


        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        System.IO.Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        System.Net.WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        System.IO.StreamReader tReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

        Response.Write(sResponseFromServer); //printing response from GCM server.
        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
```

i tried few answers from the previous questions but nothing is working out 
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `registration_ids` with `registration_id`.The [HTTP Connection Server Reference](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) explains that `registration_ids` is only valid in JSON formatted requests:

**registration_ids**

> Use this parameter only for multicast messaging, not for single
>   recipients. Multicast messages (sending to more than 1 registration
>   tokens) are allowed using HTTP JSON format only.

Comment: when i replaced registration_ids with registration_id i am getting Error=NotRegistered @qbix

Comment: The possible causes for `NotRegistered` are [explained here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes).  You may need to register the device again.